# OSQL IPEDS LOOP

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, osql

Trying to load IPEDS data zip files in an Oracle DB.
Data: https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/use-the-data/download-access-database
26 Tables with data mapping for table names, titles, etc. As well as variable names, Code Values, Value labels, etc. by Year

The data has table keys such as SurveyOrder, SurveyNumber, Tablenumber, TableName. Specifically, I need to map/assign Codevalue to variable names.

I have tried my research at the Loop function in OSQL but struggling. Anyone have sample code they are willing to share? Better yet, anyone out this higher ed created this process already?

Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeCP9.png)

Comment: 1. I think OSQL is for MS SQL Server. However, your question mentioned Oracle. 2. What do you mean by "map/assign Codevalue to variable names."? 3. Is it a requirement to use the "Loop function", or you just want to do the Codevalue mapping?

Comment: Hi @FatP. Thanks for the question. I am just trying to quickly move through codevalue mapping and naming structure.